Does Sybase ASE support SSL with kerberos authentication
I am using the Sybase ASE SSL with password based authentication for Sybase ASE and that is working perfectly.
I would like to enable the SSL with kerberos authentication for JDBC connectivity to encrypt the communication b/w server & client.
Setting the data source property newDS.setENABLE_SSL("true"); is not working and jdbc connection failed.
Is it possible or not?
